# The check does not work:- if (isset ($_PHP["form_name"]))

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

There are several forms for queries in the file, you need to do a form check, if you do not do this, all forms with queries are executed, as for me it is not correct. Here with the help of `if (isset($_POST ['form_name']))` I do a check, but does not exit. What is the problem?

---

```
<form id="form" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]"> 
   <input type="text" name="telephone[]">       
   <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="form_ex">
   <button type="submit" name="update" id="btn_post_phones" value="button_value">Update phone</button>
</form>
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {  
      var_dump ('true -->');
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"], true));
} else {
      var_dump ('false-->');
      echo "<pre>";
      var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"], true));
}

//string(8) "false-->"
//array(2) {
//  [0]=>
//  string(6) "345345"
//  [1]=>
//  string(6) "345345"
//}
```

---

```
$('#form').submit(function(event) {
var arrPhones = new Array();  
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[name="telephone[]"]').each(
        function() {
            arrPhones.push($(this).val()); 
        });
    var data='phones='+JSON.stringify(arrPhones);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'regist.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data:  data,
        // data:  $('input[name="telephone[]"]').serialize,
        beforeSend: function(){
            console.log('before ' + data);
        },
        success: function(response){ 
          console.log(response);
        }       
    });
});
```

Comment: `if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {...}` never happened.

Comment: Error reporting would have thrown you something about an undefined index, did you know that?

Comment: There are a few problems with this actually. firstly.. `$_POST['form_name']` just doesn't exist? looks like copy-paste error. At least in what code you have shared.

Comment: You are sending only phone numbers in JS, no other info

Comment: This is a repost of your https://stackoverflow.com/q/49776170/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transferring the JSON array, AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776170/transferring-the-json-array-ajax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Remove `var data='phones='+JSON.stringify(arrPhones);`

2.instead of `data:  data,` write `data:{'phones':JSON.stringify(arrPhones)},`

3.Instead of `if (isset($_POST['form_name'])) {...}`  use `if (isset($_POST['phones'])) {...}`

Comment: @МишаПодлевских glad to help you :):)

Comment: @МишаПодлевских  consider marking answers on all your posts which actually solved your problem. This will help future visitors to get their answer quickly as well as you will gain reputation too.